# Getting Facebook Profile URL in Facebook App API 2.0: is it possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In API 2.0, the Username and ID User don't exist anymore.

Is it possible to get profile URL from any app user?

Comment: Yes the user request contains a link property

Comment: facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id works.

Comment: For me, the link worked only when the user clicks on your own link. When a user clicks the link from another user, I get error 404. 

But so far I only tests with users tests.